# Opening FTP files in cycle

Tags: php, ftp

i have cycle for.
I`m opening file that name is stored in array from FTP.

```
$contents = ftp_nlist($conn_id, "."); //17

for($i = 0; $i < count($contents); $i++){ //$i < 17
    $filename = 'ftp://name:pass@host/'.$contents[$i];
    $handle = fopen($filename, "r");
    $contents = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
    fclose($handle);
    echo $contents;
}
```

But there is problem that after first echo it no long works. It just prints the content of first file, not of another 16.

Comment: i`ve solved it with $file = file_get_contents('ftp://name:pass@host/'.$contents[$i]);
    echo $file;

Answer (score 0):

You reassign `$contents` in your loop, negating the condition of your for loop...

```
$contents = ftp_nlist($conn_id, "."); //17

for($i = 0; $i < count($contents); $i++){ //$i < 17
    $filename = 'ftp://name:pass@host/'.$contents[$i];
    $handle = fopen($filename, "r");
    $NOTGONNAOVERWRITEcontents = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
    fclose($handle);
    echo $NOTGONNAOVERWRITEcontents;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just from looking at the code, I would say the problem is the line

```
$contents = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
```

There you replace $contents with the content of $handle. After doing this, $contents is not longer the list you expect it to be.

Solution could be to take the output from fread() into another variable, like

```
$thisContent = fread(...);
```